# Fixed background layer behind scrollable front container

Tags: html, css

This is how I try to make the wrapper container scrollable over the footer element.

The footer should be fixed in the background, so it shouldn't move. I want to give the user the feeling he is moving the wrapper layer upwards to take a look at the fixed background footer.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/nature_waterfall_summer_lake_trees_90400_3840x2160.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<footer>This content should stay fixed on bottom of footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The edited code for you

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  
  z-index: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/nature_waterfall_summer_lake_trees_90400_3840x2160.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #555;
       position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
      Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>
      Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>
     Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>
     Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>
     Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>
 </div>
<footer>This content should stay fixed on bottom of footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the fixed footer give `position:fixed;bottom:0;`
For parallax scrolling refer : [Parallax](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/)

Answer (score -1):

See the materialize [fixed footer](http://materializecss.com/footer.html)